# Invoking a button press in a desktop application from an external application when HWND and control automation ID are known

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, autohotkey, ui-automation

I am trying to automate button presses for a desktop application on Windows 7 - 10. I have been able to do this using AutoHotKey and PowerShell. However, I have had the following issues:

1. The controls I am trying to click do not have text that I can use to
   isolate the control
2. The ClassNN name for the components is not
   static

I have looked through the MSDN documentation for the `System.Windows.Automation` namespace, but the documentation doesn't provide actual examples or describe how to use the namespace.

**Question**

If I always have a window handle (`HWND`) and an Automation ID for a control, how do I invoke a button press on the control using AutoHotKey, PowerShell(3.0+), or C#?

Comment: I usually use AutoIt, but anyway ... . In order to resolve similar tasks I usually position the window at fixed position `(0, 0)` (and size, maximize if available) and click at the "right" coordinates (I get them in Photoshop or similar from a screenshot), as long as the code runs on my pc, so the position/size doesn't change I'm good. It's a hacky solution, but if it works ...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with C# and System.Windows.Automation.
First of all get your control as an AutomationElement (let's call it thiselement).
Then you can invoke InvokePattern to perform click action.

```
    InvokePattern ip;
    ip = thiselement.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as       
    InvokePattern;
    ip.Invoke();
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. Just to repeat the question, I have a window handle / process ID and the automation ID for the element. How do I invoke a button press if I have those elements? You've provided the file step which is invoke the object, but that is based on the assumption that you already have the object in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your window handle is 'handle' and automation id of the button is 'automationId' then you can do something like

```
AutomationElement parentWin = AutomationElement.FromHandle(handle);
Condition c1 = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, 
automationId);
AutomationElement thiselement = parentWin.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, c1);
```

once you get the button object,just invoke the InvokePattern  .Please forgive the foramatting of text